# How to Undo an "Import Settings" in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, undo

How do I revert or undo the changes made after using the "Import Settings" option in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting the jar file used to import settings. Mine was located in my Download directory. Shutdown IntelliJ, delete the jar file and retart IntelliJ.

I also deleted the `colors.scheme.xml` file located in:

`$USERHOME\.IntelliJIdea14\config\options`

Comment: Note that his will not revert/undo back to what you had before the import. It will undo back to the default settings. Still better than nothing though.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to reset configuration to default, you need to do the following:
I Have PhpStorm Version 2018.1 on Mac : that's work for every jetbrains Product just change the name and version.

```
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2018.1"
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Caches/PhpStorm2018.1"
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Application Support/PhpStorm2018.1"
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Logs/PhpStorm2018.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme`. There you can change the color schema to whatever you would love to have using "Scheme" drop down.